# ROAuth twitter streaming-API in R?

Tags: r, twitter-streaming-api

I am following streamR pkg documentation available at -https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/streamR/streamR.pdf

steps that, I had followed so far--

```
library(ROAuth)
library(streamR)
requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "my consumer key"
consumerSecret <- " my secret key"

my_oauth <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumerKey, consumerSecret =         consumerSecret,requestURL = requestURL, accessURL = accessURL, authURL = authURL)
my_oauth$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

the code works fine for me for the first,  but after that,I am getting following error--
    Error: Authorization Required.

suggest me what is wrong with this procedure?

Comment: @Ronak, I think this is not an older way of twitter authorization and the  above link will work for twitter API not for streaming.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I read the question incorrectly.